# Backing up the replica using barman in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, barman

I'm currently backing up my master postgres db server to barman using rsync.
I want to start backing up from the standby.
Currently the master is archiving wals to barman.
I tried to just have barman connect to the slave using the cinninfo and ssh_conninfo parameters, but because the slave is not archiving (but the master is), the barman refuses to start the backup.
I can set up the slave to archive wals to the barman itself, but then if the slave is behind, I may have data loss in case of a disaster.

What is the recommend way to go? Is there any way to archive wals from the master, but backup from the standby?

Thanks!

P.S - I also tried to point the primary_conninfo to the master, but the problem is with the fact that the slave is not archiving.